# Best way to associate two strings of text in VB.NET

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, list

I've got two strings that I want to associate together so that I can search by username and get the computername.
Strings:
username
computername

I'm not that fluent in VB code so I don't know how to build this object.
This is what I think I need:

```
(
  ("user1" "computer1")
  ("user2" "computer2")
  ("user3" "computer3")
  ("user4" "computer4")
  ("user5" "computer5")
)
```

Then I want to be able to query the list by asking:
What computername is associated with "user3"? And get "computer3" as the result.

Comment: if "userX" can be expected to be unique use a dictionary, otherwise maybe a `List(of UsrComputerClass))`

Comment: Do you need also to query for computername? I.E. What user uses 'computer5' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose there is the possibility that one computer is used by more than one user, and more than one user could use a particular computer. In that case, it is probably going to be simpler to have a class which holds the information relating a user to a computer. You can then make a List of instances of that class to hold the entire set of information, and being a List, you can easily query it with LINQ, like this:

```
Option Infer On
Module Module1

    Dim computerUsers As New List(Of ComputerUser)

    Class ComputerUser
        Property ComputerName As String
        Property UserName As String
    End Class

    Sub CreateTestData()
        computerUsers = New List(Of ComputerUser)
        computerUsers.Add(New ComputerUser With {.ComputerName = "PC1", .UserName = "Fred"})
        computerUsers.Add(New ComputerUser With {.ComputerName = "PC2", .UserName = "Jim"})
        computerUsers.Add(New ComputerUser With {.ComputerName = "PC3", .UserName = "Jane"})
        computerUsers.Add(New ComputerUser With {.ComputerName = "PC1", .UserName = "Jim"})

    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        CreateTestData()

        Dim pcName = "PC1"
        Dim thisPcUsers = computerUsers.Where(Function(x) x.ComputerName = pcName).Select(Function(y) y.UserName).ToList()
        Console.WriteLine(pcName & " is used by: " & String.Join(", ", thisPcUsers))

        Dim user = "Jim"
        Dim thisUserPCs = computerUsers.Where(Function(x) x.UserName = user).Select(Function(y) y.ComputerName).ToList()
        Console.WriteLine(user & " uses computers: " & String.Join(", ", thisUserPCs))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Which outputs

```
PC1 is used by: Fred, Jim
Jim uses computers: PC2, PC1
```

**Edit** +1 to Seth, whose answer I did not see while I was writing this.

**Edit 2** You can use LINQ in various ways, for example to get the users whose names start with "J*":

```
Dim partialName = "J*"
Dim usersWithWildcard = computerUsers.Where(Function(x) x.UserName Like partialName).ToList()

Console.WriteLine("Users starting with " & partialName)
For Each u In usersWithWildcard
    Console.WriteLine(u.UserName)
Next
```

Comment: I have got the code working and have computerUsers and thisUserPCs.  How do I test to see if a user is even in computerUsers?  How would I pump the String.Join(", ", thisUserPCs) into a listbox?  I'm even wondering how to verify a user exists in computerUsers with a wildcard (start typing br... and it will filter to all of the users that start with br*)

Comment: For example: the form loads and finds all of the computers that match the user * (all of them).  It fills the list box with the list of computers.  A user starts typing in the username text box and the computer list begins to filter down as they type.

Comment: @bowlingbrad I've edited my answer to include an example of using VB's `Like` with a wildcard. You should attempt to learn about LINQ.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for a [`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx). Specifically a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`.

[`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) items one at a time:

```
Dim computers As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
computers.Add("user1", "computer1")
computers.Add("user2", "computer2")
'...
```

Or, you can use an [initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx) and do it in one fell swoop:

```
Dim computers As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From
    {
      {"user1" "computer1"},
      {"user2" "computer2"},
      {"user3" "computer3"},
      {"user4" "computer4"},
      {"user5" "computer5"}
    }
```

And access individual elements using an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim result As String = computers("user3")
```

Note this will throw an exception if "user3" does not exist in the collection. You may wish to look into [`TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if there is a possibility to search for nonexistent keys.

Answer (score 1):

While the answers using dictionary will surely work, I personally prefer to use a class and and list.

You'd do something like this:

```
Public Class UserComputer
    Private _user As String
    Public Property User() As String
        Get
            Return _user
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _user = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _comp As String
    Public Property Computer() As String
        Get
            Return _comp
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _comp = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(User As String, Computer As String)
      Me.User = User
      Me.Computer = Computer
    End Sub

End Class

Public Sub Main()
  Dim myList As New List(Of UserComputer)
  myList.Add(New UserComputer("user1", "computer1")
  '... keep adding objects
End Sub
```

The advantage here is that it becomes very easy to extend your class `UserComputer` should you need to; just add more properties to the class. It also let's you easily consume the information in the objects in other parts of your program.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that want you want is a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`:

```
Dim x as New Dictionary(Of String, String)
x.Add("user1", "computer1") ' etc...

Dim computer as String = x("user1")
```

Comment: Now, how do I trap for an error?  Say x("user6") returns an error.

Comment: You can use the `.ContainsKey` method to see whether `"user6"` exists, or you can use `TryGetValue` to get the value - which uses a `ByRef` parameter and will return `false` if there's no matching key.

Comment: I don't know if I'm using these correctly.  I put in x("user6").ContainsKey or x("user6").TryGetValue and vs2010 isn't recognizing them.

Comment: You just need `x.ContainsKey("user6")` - or for `TryGetValue` you declare a variable for the output and use `x.TryGetValue("user6", computerName)`, which will return `True` if the value existed.

Comment: Here's another question... What if a user has two computers associated with him?  What will x("user2") return if there are two entries with this username?

Comment: I just tested it and found that you cannot have more than one "user2".  Is there a way to do this?  Can I add a third value to the dictionary array?  Maybe Dictionary(Of Integer, String, String)?

Comment: @bowlingbrad You can have a `Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim userComputers As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From
{   
   {"user1" "computer1"},
   {"user2" "computer2"},
   {"user3" "computer3"},
   {"user4" "computer4"},
   {"user5" "computer5"}
}

Dim computer As String = userComputers("user3")
```

Comment: Joel, Sorry I wasn't clear.  I'm using the class now and not the dictionary.